# Passing props to element attributes in Vue components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

When I try passing props to attributes of HTML elements in `.vue` files, they just stop rendering. What am I doing wrong?

**script.js**

```
import hInput from './components/hInput.vue'
Vue.component('h-input', hInput);
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#head',
});
```

**index.php**

```
<div id="head">
    <h1>{{config('app.name')}}</h1>
    <h-input placeholder="Hi" name="hello"></h-input>
</div>
```

**hInput.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="{{placeholder}}">
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['placeholder', 'name']
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the [binding syntax](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Attributes), not text interpolation.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <input type="text" v-bind:placeholder="placeholder">
    </div>
</template>
```

There is also a shorthand.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <input type="text" :placeholder="placeholder">
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Cheers. Can you tell me how to use an external plugin inside this .vue file? Specifically vee-validate, I used Vue.use(VeeValidate), it works directly outside components files but not inside. Do  I import it somehow?

Comment: @Mav I believe `Vue.use(VeeValidate)` in `script.js` *should* make it available in your single file components. Where are you calling it?

Comment: No docs until now. Thanks a lot, this really saves my day!